# WiX HowTo: Downgrade a third-party dependency without re-installing?

Tags: wix, windows-installer, installation, dependency-management

### Background

*WiX* & the *Windows Installer* are completely new to me.

In production, we used an MSI (created using WiX) to install our software.  The MSI references a third-party assembly (e.g. OtherCompany.ThirdParty.dll, version 2.5).

The next release of our software **must** reference an older version of the third-party assembly (e.g. OtherCompany.ThirdParty.dll, version 1.7).

While I understand that installing an older version of a dependency is uncommon, it must happen.

So my question is... how do you configure a MSI (generated by WiX) to use an older version of an assembly without having to completely uninstall the existing package?

### Options

We have explored the following:

1. Increment the assembly's version

   - it's a third party assembly, and
   - for traceability this is not an option
2. rename the assembly

   - the dependency is being retrieved using NuGet... so this won't be straight forward
3. force existing install to be completely removed (automatically or manually)

   - we don't want configuration information that was collected during the previous installation to be lost, so this isn't an option
4. schedule `RemoveExistingProducts` before costing

   - not recommended by Microsoft (see: [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa371197(v=vs.85).aspx))
5. custom action: to delete dependency

   - if the installation fails, the application may be left in an undefined state
6. override file version in setup

   - moving forward, this will be error prone
7. changing the REINSTALLMODE

   - From the articles that I have read, it appears that this should only be used as a last resort.
8. use a WIX companion file

   - am still investigating

### For Moderators

I am aware that there are other SO posts on this subject.  Please note that several of the recommended solutions are incomplete or are error prone.

### References

- [MSDN: Patching and Upgrades](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370579(v=vs.85).aspx)
- [MSDN: RemoveExistingProducts Action](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa371197(v=vs.85).aspx)
- [downgrade a library during a msi upgrade](http://howdididothatthingagain.blogspot.ca/2015/07/wix-and-msi-installers-downgrade.html)
- [Why Windows Installer removes files during a major upgrade if they go backwards in version numbers](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/astebner/2015/11/16/why-windows-installer-removes-files-during-a-major-upgrade-if-they-go-backwards-in-version-numbers/)
- [MSI Writing Guidelines](https://wyrdfish.wordpress.com/2012/07/20/msi-writing-guidelines-this-may-be-out-of-date/)
- [What Every Developer Should Know About MSI Components](http://geekswithblogs.net/akraus1/archive/2011/06/17/145898.aspx)
- [Windows installer deletes versioned file during product upgrade, instead of downgrading it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4227456/windows-installer-deletes-versioned-file-during-product-upgrade-instead-of-down?rq=1)
- [MSDN: Windows Installer - File Versioning Rules](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368599.aspx)
- [Msiexec REINSTALL=ALL REINSTALLMODE=vamus not reinstalling anything](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6372818/949681)

  - good overview of what is happening under-the-hood
- [Forcing an upgrade of a file that is modified during its initial installation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1434514/949681)

  - this is an older post is from 2009

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some issues are best solved by the application design rather the deployment.

There are two places to save a particular version of a .NET assembly: the GAC or the application folder (or subfolder with [probing privatePath](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/runtime/probing-element)). In either case, you might want to use a [bindingRedirect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/runtime/bindingredirect-element).

Also, you can load from a specific location using [AppDomain.AssemblyResolve](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.assemblyresolve%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), *provided the binding is not successful using the GAC.*

General Reference: [How the Runtime Locates Assemblies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/deployment/how-the-runtime-locates-assemblies)—thanks to @Pressacco.

Comment: Thank you Tom. The final solution: <1> removed the `OtherCompany.ThirdParty.dll` (version 2.5) from the installer, <2> added `OtherCompany.ThirdParty.dll` (version 1.7) to the installer so that the DLL is installed to a new directory, and <3> took advantage of [probing](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/runtime/probing-element) to load the assembly from the new path. **Note** to other developers who are going to implement this... assembly loading behaves differently for signed vs unsigned assemblies. See MSDN: How the Runtime Locates Assemblies